# http to https migration in Jenkins not working

Tags: jenkins, https, keytool, jks, pkcs#12

We need to migrate the Jenkins URL from http to https.
We have a server where Jenkins is installed and the jobs are running fine.
Now for the security enhancement we need to migrate to https.

We received a pkcs12 certificate. Now to include the certificate , the following steps was followed

1. Using the keytool , converted the pkcs12 to jks format.
   Command used

   keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore D:\Installations\JENKINS_HOME\httpsCertificate\certificate.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore D:\Installations\JENKINS_HOME\httpsCertificate\certificate.jks -deststoretype JKS
2. To include the jks certificate , changed the jenkins xml file with the following arguments

   --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8443 --httpsKeyStore="D:\Installations\JENKINS_HOME\httpsCertificate\certificate.jks" --httpsKeyStorePassword=***** --httpsListenAddress="0.0.0.0"
3. Restarted Jenkins service

But after the restart even though it was mapped to https but showing as not secure
[The Jenkins URL after the migration process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE0pn.png)

Comment: Probably you are using a self-signed certificate. Click on the Padlock Icon and check the certificate details.

Comment: @ycr Thank you for the reply. I checked the Issuer and Subject of the certificate. The values are different . So I think it is not a self-signed certificate.

Comment: Which CA has issued the certificate? What domain name is mentioned in it's subjectAlternative extension? What URL do you use to access Jenkins (you have to use the fully qualified domain name, not the short local name without domain name).

Comment: @Robert Thank you for the reply.
We received the certificate from our company.
Subject : CN = <serverName>.<CompanyNetwork>.com
URL used to access Jenkins : https://<serverName>:8443/

Comment: The subject is the wrong place. Modern web tools only check the subjectAlternative attribute.

Comment: @Robert I will check with this info . So exactly what can be done now in this case ?

Comment: If the certificate is missing the subjectAlternative extension or the extension contains not all necessary dns names then you can only throw away the certificate and generate a new correct one.

Comment: @Robert I tried the way you told and it worked !!! --  "to use the fully qualified domain name, not the short local name without domain name"

In my case I was trying the URL 
-- https://<serverName>:8443/  
instead I tried 
--- https://<serverName>.<CompanyNetwork>.com:8443/ 
same as in the certificate hostname and it worked

Thank you for your guidance !!